# Why is my custom post type not showing in the admin menu?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress, and have built a dummy plugin in to see how the the wordpress custom plugin will work. For some reason when I activate it I don't see the plugin name in the sidebar? I have looked over my code several times and can't seem to figure out the problem. If anyone knows what I am doing wrong here, I would really appreciate it!!!

Below is my code

```
<?php
/*Plugin Name: Custom Cpt */


class Cpt {



    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action("registerPostType",[$this,"Cpt"]);
    }

    function registerPostType(){


        $labels = [

            "name"=> __("Products"),
            "singular_name" => __("Product"),
            "edit_name" => "Edit Products",
            "new_item"  => "New Products",
            "view_item"=>"View products",
            "menu_name"  => "Products",
            "name_admin_bar"=> "Products"


        ];


        $args = [

            "labels" => $labels,
            "has_archive" => true,
            "public"        => true,
            "show_in_menu"=>true,
            "show_in_admin_bar"=>true,
            "menu_icon" => "dashicons-admin-multisite",
            "hierarchical"=> true,


        ];


        register_post_type("custom_post",$args);



    }


}

new Cpt();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This

```
add_action('init',[$this,'registerPostType'] );
```

If not in constructor. Use

```
add_action('init','registerPostType' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what the issue was, the add_action method in the construct needed to be

```
add_action("init",[$this,"registerPostType"]);
```